# What is the difference between Domain Handlers and Application Services in Project Silk?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, architecture, domain-driven-design

This is specifically in reference usage of DDD in [Project Silk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404097.aspx) .

The project uses DDD and has the concept of **Handlers** and **Services** implemented.
What exactly is the difference and use case for these 2 types?

For instance, there is a service `UserServices` for creation of User.
But the creation fo Vehicle is done in a Handler.

Would like to know the reasoning behind this decision.

**Domain\UserServices**

```
public class UserServices : IUserServices
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

        public UserServices(IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            if (userRepository == null) 
                  throw new ArgumentNullException("userRepository");
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }


        public User CreateUser(User newUser)
        {
            if (newUser == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("newUser");
            try
            {
                Model.User userToAdd = ToDataModelUser(newUser);
                this.userRepository.Create(userToAdd);
                return ToServiceUser(userToAdd);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                throw new BusinessServicesException
                            (Resources.UnableToCreateUserExceptionMessage, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Domain\Handlers\CreateVehicle.cs**

```
public class CreateVehicle
    {
        private readonly IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepository;
        private readonly IVehiclePhotoRepository _photoRepository;

        public CreateVehicle(IVehicleRepository vehicleRepository,
                 IVehiclePhotoRepository photoRepository)
        {
            _vehicleRepository = vehicleRepository;
            _photoRepository = photoRepository;
        }

        public virtual void Execute(int userId, 
                         ICreateVehicleCommand vehicleForm,  
                          HttpPostedFileBase photoFile)
        { 

            if (vehicleForm == null) throw 
                           new ArgumentNullException("vehicleForm");

            try
            {
                var vehicle = vehicleForm.ConvertToEntity(userId);
                _vehicleRepository.Create(userId, vehicle);

                if (photoFile == null) return;

                // the double reference between vehicle and photo 
               //is a potential source of pain
                var photo = photoFile.ConvertToEntity();
                _photoRepository.Create(vehicle.VehicleId, photo);
                vehicle.PhotoId = photo.VehiclePhotoId;

                _vehicleRepository.Update(vehicle);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                throw new BusinessServicesException  
                    (Resources.UnableToCreateVehicleExceptionMessage, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would imagine that it's in no small part because User Management is considered a broad-based system activity (you're going to need it regardless of your problem domain), while a Vehicle is actually part of *your* defined problem domain.  Notice that UserServices derives from IUserServices.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I noticed the UserServices comprises of using just the IUserRepository but the handlers have multiple Repositories in play. Is that a requirement that services should be comprised of just its own repository?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I can't imagine why you'd need more than one for UserServices.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  So the only reason Users are not handled in Handlers is because they can be exposed as an application service  to mutliple, different  external calls? While problem domain specific handlers are invoked only by their specific controller? Is that a fair conclusion?

Comment: I'd have to look more closely to the source code to see what's going on there, but it doesn't have much to do with Silk per se.  Silk is a client-side architecture; what you're talking about here is all in the Model.  Probably has more to do with DDD than anything else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, you're correct. Its all about DDD with Silk source code for domain models as a reference.

Comment: And DDD doesn't speak to these Handler methods as such?  User Management has always been part of the ASP.NET machine proper, and doesn't really have much to do with DDD.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35799/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-gillivilla)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I think the difference is the creation of user is an active action of user while the creation of viecle is a passive one. Someone submits a form to create a user, on the other hand, it triggers to create a viecle after some operation is done(maybe after a user is created?).

Maybe you'll interested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086266/in-ddd-who-should-be-resposible-for-handling-domain-events/18094436#18094436).